# Intel AX200 wifi card not found on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

Hi I've been struggling with this for several days now

I have a PC that i'm dual booting with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04, the Window's 10 OS is working fine, however I've had massive issues with getting wifi working on my Ubuntu OS.

Mobo: Gigabyte X570

Wificard: Intel AX200

I first started with ubuntu 18.04 but was unable to get the wifi to work after several days of  trying different solutions, one answer said they were able to solve the problem by switching to a newer distro, so I decided to try 20.04

The first time I installed 20.04 the wifi worked during installation so I thought everything was fine, however after install was completed the wifi no longer worked. I have since uninstalled and then reinstalled 20.04 however wifi no longer works during installation.

secureboot is disabled
rfkill list gives no response
sudo modprobe iwlwifi gives no response
sudo modprope -r iwlwifi gives no response

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlw
[  123.575129] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  123.708064] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with error -110

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -nn | grep Network
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lshw -class network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
...etc...
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7600000-f7603fff
```

fixes tried on 18.04:
-copying firmware file downloaded from intel website into firmware directory
-kernel was 5.3, the newer kernel solved the problem for some people
-backport iwlwifi package, i can't remember what exactly this was a couple of days ago, but i remember messing with this

Comment: Please reboot so that we have a clean slate and run: `dmesg | grep iwl` We need to see much more than what you posted above. If, as I suspect, the output is lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: dmesg | grep iwl, and sudo dmesg | grep iwl return the same as what i wrote in the question, even after reboot

Comment: Let's also see what's happening or not on the PCI bus: `dmesg | grep 05:00` Also, is this a possible issue? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: `[    0.180425] pci 0000:05:00.0: [8086:2723] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.180469] pci 0000:05:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7600000-0xf7603fff 64bit]
[    0.180636] pci 0000:05:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.281821] pci 0000:05:00.0: Adding to iommu group 0
[    4.392369] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.540074] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with error -110`

Comment: Will check if fast boot is enabled some time today and get back to you

Comment: Disabled fast boot and wifi card is now detected and working! Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Followed chili555's recommendation, disabled fast boot on my Windows OS, and then wifi card was recognised and working! I couldn't figure out how to set their comment as the answer, and I just wanted to make it clear for anyone looking at the question how this issue was solved.
Thanks chili555!

Comment: This seemed to fix my issue too!