# Unable to detect Wifi Adapter. Ubuntu 20.04 . Razer Blade 2019: Intel AX-200

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I am new to Linux-Ubuntu and I am currently dual booting with windows. I had no issues with wifi initially but lately my system could not detect the wifi adapter.

I tried a couple of solutions from

[Unable to get wifi adapter working - clean 19.04 install - network unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed/1156246#1156246)

[Intel AX200 wifi card not found on ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253988/intel-ax200-wifi-card-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04)

some suggested following the instructions here

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

```
dmesg | grep iwl showed 

[    3.377570] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    3.377571] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
[    3.559520] iwlwifi 0000:3f:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.917475] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:3f:00.0 failed with error -110
```

I am not sure if there is suppose to be any response when running sudo modprobe iwlwifi but there were none

nothing seems to be working. (disabling fastboot/ secureboot makes no difference)

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help guide me through this.

edit:

couple of days ago I updated my Wifi driver from windows and the wifi adapter was found on linux and it was working again. However, due to the recent update of ubuntu, the wifi adapter is not found again.

Comment: I am no expert but post the result of `lspci -vnn | grep Network` so that a real expert can advise you further.

Comment: it shows. 3f:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, the problem I faced was probably due to windows.

[No wifi adapter found! Dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984303/no-wifi-adapter-found-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-17-10)

following the steps from the link above made my wifi work again on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Today i will show you how to get your WiFI card working properly on you Razer Blade Pro 17 dual booted into any version of Linux OS Kali, Ubuntu etc.. And this will also work on any other razer blade model. My WiFI card is currently a Wi-Fi 6E AX210 Intel card.

1. Download the WiFI drivers on the intel website for your particular WiFI Card in your computer https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html save it anywhere. I will save it in Downloads
2. Open Terminal in Linux and go to directory where you downloaded the Intel WiFi driver and type: "Ls" to display everything in Downloads folder. Next type: tar zxvf iwlwifi-ty-59.601f3a66.0.tgz this will extract the folder.
3. The folder should be extracted. Direct into the extracted folder using these commands: cd iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0
4. Next copy the .ucode file to the firmware folder listed in the lib folder sudo cp iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode /lib/firmware
5. NEXT STEP IS VERY IMPORTANT. You need to make sure your kernel is 5.12.0 or later which most people computers are not and that's why these steps above don't work for you! type: uname -a in the terminal and it should see 5.12.0 or later if not PLEASE follow step 6.
6. If your kernel is not 5.12.0 or later you must upgrade your kernel via terminal. Follow and type all of these commands in the terminal step by step.

   ```
    cd /tmp/        
    wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12/amd64/linux-headers-5.12.0-051200_5.12.0-051200.202104252130_all.deb
    wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12/amd64/linux-headers-5.12.0-051200-generic_5.12.0-051200.202104252130_amd64.deb
    wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.12.0-051200-generic_5.12.0-051200.202104252130_amd64.deb
    wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12/amd64/linux-modules-5.12.0-051200-generic_5.12.0-051200.202104252130_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
7. After these have been successfully completed you should be on the latest kernel necessary in order for your OS(Linux) to recognize you WiFi card(AX210 WiFi6E). Reboot and you should see the WiFi symbol.

Uninstall kernel back to original if needed type:
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-unsigned-5.12.0-051200-generic
YOU'RE WELCOME!!