# Ubuntu 18.04 - Wireless Adapter not Found

Tags: 18.04, wireless, iwlwifi, adapter

My wifi  spuriously failed to connect this morning.  Last night, left it asleep, working just fine and this morning it was unable to connect to the internet with a
No-Wifi-Adapter-Found error.
Outputs:

- `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:911a4000-911a7fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20f0u4
       serial: ae:6c:d3:65:74:87
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.77 link=yes multicast=yes
```

- `iw list`: no output.
  `sudo rfkill list`:

```
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

- `iwconfig:`  no wireless connections for lo and eth.
- `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` :

`[  351.373357]  psmouse ahci intel_ish_ipc libahci intel_ishtp i2c_hid hid wmi pinctrl_cannonlake video pinctrl_intel [last unloaded: iwlwifi] [  351.373407] RIP: 0010:iwl_pci_probe+0x4da/0x540 [iwlwifi] [  351.373520]  iwl_pci_register_driver+0x24/0x40 [iwlwifi] [  351.373547]  __init_backport+0xb8/0xe0 [iwlwifi] [  351.406765] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22`

I have

- restarted several times
- disabled Secure Boot
- ran `sudo rfkill unblock all`
- ran `sudo rmmod iwlmvm && sudo modprobe iwlmvm`
- ran`sudo service network-manager restart`
- unpacked the iwlwifi 5.2+ firmware into lib/firmware
- changed wifi.powersave to 2 in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
- ran `modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0`
- ran
  `sudo apt update  sudo apt install git build-essential git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git cd backport-iwlwifi/ make defconfig-iwlwifi-public sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config make -j4 sudo make install sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

I'm at my wits end, any advice on how to fix would be much appreciated.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Are you by any chance dual booting with Windows? It took me ages to find out that the problem was caused by 'fast boot' option in Windows 10. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253988/intel-ax200-wifi-card-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04#comment2118851_1253988